# how to deploy an application to a particular ubuntu server using azure-devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have my code in the azure repos.I have created the release pipeline which runs the task "npm install" and "npm run start".This will deploy my application.But I  want to deploy this application to my ubuntu server 206.189.22.155 from the azure release pipeline.Is there any way I can configure the release pipeline to use my ubuntu server?

The only agent pool available for me is "Azure Pipelines" and for agent specification I used "ubuntu-16.04".Iam totally confused about how this works.
I just want my application to run on http://206.189.22.155:5000. I can run the application directly in the server, but the whole point is to run it from the release pipeline.So how do I connect the pipeline to my ubuntu server?I think my default azure uses some kind of virtual machine for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a deployment group in Azure DevOps. Deployment groups in Azure pipelines make it easier to organize the servers you want to use to host your app. In Azure pipelines -> Devployment group, select “+New” button and type of target to register. Copy and run the Registration script in your Ubuntu server. 
[image]

You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-linuxvm-deploygroups?view=azure-devops&tabs=java-script#define-your-ci-build-pipeline and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/index?view=azure-devops for more detailed information

After you create the deployment group, you can choose it in your release pipeline
[image]

And after you configure you deployment group, you can deploy your app to the specific server.
[image]

Comment: ok i did what you said...i created a deployment group called "vignesh" then tried to run the release pipeline but then i got an error saying "No machine found in given deployment group with tags"